# What English dialect adds an 'r' after a 'w' in certain cases?

Tags: dialects, british-english

While watching videos online I've heard multiple brits pronounce "drawing" as "drawring". What dialect does that? Please contribute more examples of this as well, as that is the only one I can currently think of.

Comment: I would suggest that this is not a duplicate question - User is asking for examples of which dialects in English use in an 'intrusive R', and the other question is asking what an 'instrusive R' is. Many English dialects do this - but most famously West Country/South West/Cornish.

Comment: Note that this is nothing to do with the w; there are no dialects that add an r after an actual /w/. It’s simply that some vowel phonemes (usually /ɔ/ and /ɒ/) happen to be represented in writing by a vowel followed by a ⟨w⟩. In cases where there is an actual /w/, though, no /r/ is inserted: _wowing_ and _hewing_ do not become /waʊrɪŋ/ (‘wowring’) and /hʲuːrɪŋ/ (‘hewring’).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the ***[intrusive R](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R):***

> - The phenomenon of intrusive R is an overgeneralizing reinterpretation of linking R into an r-insertion rule that affects any word that ends in the non-high vowels /ə/, /ɪə/, /ɑː/, or /ɔː/; when such a word is closely followed by another word beginning in a vowel sound, an [r] is inserted between them, even when no final /r/ was historically present.
> - ***These phenomena occur in many non-rhotic varieties of English, such as those in most of England and Wales, part of the United States, and all of the Anglophone societies of the southern hemisphere***, with the exception of South Africa. These phenomena first appeared in English sometime after the year 1700.
> - Other recognizable examples are the Beatles singing: "I saw-r-a film today, oh boy" in the song "A Day in the Life", from their 1967 Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band album, in the song "Champagne Supernova" by Oasis: "supernova-r-in the sky".,,
> - ***This is now common enough in parts of England*** that, by 1997, the linguist John C. Wells considered it objectively part of Received Pronunciation, though he noted that it was still stigmatized as an incorrect pronunciation, as it is or was in some other standardized non-rhotic accents. Wells writes that at least in RP, "linking /r/ and intrusive /r/ are distinct only historically and orthographically".
> - ***Just like linking R, intrusive R may also occur between a root morpheme and certain suffixes, such as draw(r)ing, withdraw(r)al or Kafka(r)esque.***

(Wikipedia)